# How can i get all related object's manytomany related field's records in Django by single query

Tags: python, django, django-models

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ManyToManyField("Author")

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ManyToManyField("Author")
```

I can get Author.objects.get(id=1).chapter_set.all() and append each chapters author to the `List` but how can i achieve this by query in Django

Comment: You can try using queryset `values_list` or `values_list` with parameter `flat=True` to get a list of all the fields or a single field from your queryset. Example: `Author.objects.get(id=1).chapter_set.values_list()` or `Author.objects.get(id=1).chapter_set.values_list('id', flat=True)`

Comment: @Martins what should I use when I need whole object

Comment: you can filter it down or get it by it's ID/PK

Comment: @Martins Do you mean after using values_list? With separate query?

Comment: Do you need all chapters with authors? `Chapter.objects.filter(author__isnull=False)` then. Not clear from "append each chapters author to the list": append author or chapters? You can filter authors who have chapters.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this.

for fetching data in python you can use like this way.

```
fetch = Chapter.objects.all()

#and then for fetch the author
for chapter in fetch:
    author_fetch = chapter.author.all()
    #and now you can access the all data from author
    print(author_fetch[0].name)
```

and for showing data to html you don't need to call author_fetch. you can directly call it in html. Here is an example

```
{% for chapter in object_list %} 
  
  {% for author in chapter.author.all %} 
     {{author.name}} 
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```